# Ruby: What can cause execution of same codeblock to slowdown over time when ran over and over again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, sidekiq

I have a background worker in my rails project that executes a lot of complicated data aggregation in-memory in ruby. I'm seeing a strange behavior. When I boot up a process for executing the jobs (thousands), I see a strange performance decrease over time. In the beginning a job completion takes around 300ms but after processing around 10.000 jobs the execution time will gradually have decreased to around 2000ms. This is a big problem for me and I'm puzzled about how this can possibly happen. I see no memory leaks (RAM usage is pretty stable), and I see no errors. What might cause this on a low level, and where should I start looking?

**Background facts:**

- Among the things the job does, it does a lot of regexp comparisons of a lot of strings. There is no external database calls made except for read/write operations to a redis instance.
- I have tried to execute the same on different servers/computers, and the symptoms are all the same.
- If I restart the process when it starts to perform too bad, the performance turns good again immediately after.

  - I'm running ruby 1.9.3p194 and rails 3.2 and sidekiq 2.9.0 for job processor

Comment: If you provide some of the code for the background data aggregation process, that may lend some insight

Comment: Thanks for you question, but sorry I think that is almost impossible to provide in a way that can really give useful insights, since it does so much. It's a top level job, that executes a whole pipeline data cleanup and aggregation. This is why I didn't ask for "What am I doing wrong in this piece of code", but instead is asking for, "what/how can a process (theoretically) gets slower and slower at executing the same code over time" - cause I don't know anything but memory leaks and there seems to be none of those.

Comment: You *might* have some O(n) or worse performance issue on a data cache - it could be small enough that you wouldn't notice when checking for general memory issues - for example a million symbols in the symbol table may only take up a few MB, but if you were iterating over them to check keys in a data structure you would notice the difference. E.g. if you symbolize_keys on a JSON hash containing arbitrary keys (different on each input), you might see this sort of behaviour after processing a few thousand if your process relies heavily on efficiency of Symbol lookups . . .

Comment: Interesting!!! I'm actually doing that quite a lot - maybe you should change that comment to an answer instead @Neil Slater BTW. what is O(n)? Can you give me a link or something?

Comment: Addition to my above comment: I think I read you comment a little too quickly, I am using symbolize_keys and symbols in general quite a lot, however I think that the key names I use is pretty static...

Comment: @Niels Kristian: I think it is unlikely to be symbols then. But please read the last para of my answer . . . a profiler could really help you here! O(n) notation is just saying that the speed performance of your code depends on some factor n by the function of n inside the O(). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @Neil Slater Confirmed, I just tried to do a puts Symbol.all_symbols.length in my job code, and the number of symbols does not change.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell from the limited description of your service, but the behaviour is consistent with a small (i.e. not leaky) cache of data that either has poor lookup performance, or that you are relying on very heavily, and that is growing at just a modest rate. A contrived example might be a list of "jobs done so far by this worker" which is being sorted on demand at a few points in the code.

One such cache is out of your direct control: Ruby's symbol table. Finding a Symbol is something like O(log(n)) on number of symbols in the system, which is good. But this could still impact you if you handle a lot of symbols, and each iteration of your worker can generate new symbols (for instance if keys in an input hash can be arbitrary data, and you use a `symbolize_keys` method or call `to_sym` on a lot of varying strings). Symbols are cached permanently in the Ruby process. In theory a few million would not show up as a memory leak. But if your code can go from say 10,000 symbols to 1,000,000 in total, all the symbol generating and checking code would slow down by a small fixed amount. If you are doing that a lot, it could potentially explain a few hundred ms.

If hunting through suspect code is getting you nowhere, your best bet to find the problem is to use a profiler. You should collect a profile of the code behaving well, and behaving badly, and compare the two.